# R shiny import leaflet html widget object

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a leaflet plot that was exported as a .rds file.
How can I now output this plot in a shiny app?
Minimal example code below of what I have tried which currently gives "Warning: Error in FUN: argument is not a character vector [No stack trace available]"

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI<-fluidPage(mainPanel(
uiOutput("test")
)
)
shinyServer<-function(input,output){
output$test<-renderUI(readRDS("./Plots/LeafletPlot.rds"))
}
shinyApp(shinyUI,shinyServer)
```

Note that I have also tried to use renderLeaflet and leafletOutput but to no avail. 
running readRDS("./Plots/LeafletPlot.rds") from the console does load the leaflet map without issue.

Any help much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: put `readRDS("./Plots/LeafletPlot.rds")` at the beginning of your app or in `global.R` and definetly use `leafletOutput` and `renderLeaflet` to map your data

Comment: Thanks @G.Cocca; this is the solution in terms of principle; however I am still having issues because the leaflet plot gets generated at a previous stage when the app gets used so I cannot load it at the beginning(outputting the plot is a conditional panel on a previous output so I cannot put it in the global.R either). Is there no way to load external files into R(conditional on previous output having been produced) from within the server?

Comment: Actually I will probably go down the route of actually producing the leaflet within the app itself rather than this intermediary exporting .rds and subsequent re-importing (I was building the app on top of an existing suite of functions, hence the existence of this .rds intermediary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create your object 
library(leaflet)

map <- leaflet::leaflet() %>%
  leaflet::addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)

saveRDS(object = map, file = "map.rds")

# Read it at the beginning

map2 <- readRDS("map.rds")

library(shiny)
shinyUI<-fluidPage(mainPanel(
  leafletOutput("test")
 )
)

shinyServer<-function(input,output){
  output$test<-renderLeaflet(map2)
}

shinyApp(shinyUI,shinyServer)
```